# PHP Jquery POST - sends duplicate data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, duplicate-data

I have a PHP form that sends data with the help of jQuery. Whenever I click "submit" I see it sends the data twice which results in double database entries and so on.

Also I am still working on how to display "errors" and Exceptions from the try/catch block.

Note: This form worked on another site, I changed just fields and where it sends the data but can't get it to work.

THANK YOU for your help.

---

## Registration form

```html
<div id="registration" class="representativeForm">
 <div class="result">
 </div>
 <div class="formbody">
  <div class="left">
   <input required="required" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
   <input required="required" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Your surname" />
   <input required="required" type="text" name="birthdate" placeholder="Your birth date" />
   <input required="required" type="text" name="nationality" placeholder="Your nationality" />
   <?php  countriesSelection($con, $_LANG, "country"); ?>
   <input required="required" type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Your Email adress" />
   <input required="required" type="text" name="position" placeholder="Your title or job position" />
   <div class="schoolSelectionfields">
    <?php schoolSelection($con, $_LANG, "schools");  ?>
   </div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="schoolnotlisted" name="schoolnotlisted" value="1">Your school is not listed? Register school here.<br />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <div class="school_register">
    <?php  schoolRepresentativeRegistration($_LANG, $con); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="form" value="representativeForm">
 <input type="submit" value="Register" id="representativeSubmit" />
</div>
```

---

## jQuery Code

```
 $("#representativeSubmit").click(function() { 

    var proceed = true;
    //simple validation at client's end
    //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields
    $("#registration.representativeForm input[required=true]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
        }
        //check invalid email
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
        }
    });
    if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
    {
        //get input field values data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'form'     : $('input[name=form]').val(),
            'name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
            'surname'    : $('input[name=surname]').val(), 
            'birthdate'  : $('input[name=birthdate]').val(), 
            'nationality'  : $('input[name=nationality]').val(), 
            'email'  : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
            'position'  : $('input[name=position]').val(), 
            'country'  : $('select[name=country]').val(), 
        };

        if($("#schoolnotlisted").prop('checked') == true) {
            post_data += {
                'schoolName'  : $('input[name=schoolName]').val(), 
                'schoolAddress'  : $('input[name=schoolAddress]').val(), 
                'schoolZipcode'  : $('input[name=schoolZipcode]').val(), 
                'schoolCity'  : $('input[name=schoolCity]').val(), 
                'schoolCountry'  : $('select[name=schoolCountry]').val()
            };
        }
        else {
            post_data += {
                'schools'  : $('select[name=schools]').val()
            };
        }
        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('registration.php', post_data, function(response){  
            if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                //reset values in all input fields
                $("#registration.representativeForm  input[required=true]").val(''); 
                $("#registration.representativeForm .formbody").slideUp(); //hide form after success
            }
            $("#registration .result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});
//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#registration.representativeForm  input[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
    $(this).css('border-color',''); 
    $(".result").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Tell me if I understand - Does it navigate to a new page? By default, clicking a `submit` button would submit the form and navigate to the action page. You might want to use `e.preventDefault` to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the event handler to the form itself rather than to the submit button and put an `event.preventDefault()` statement in there. As you did not post your form code, I have simply named it "form".

```
$( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // here comes everything from the click handler attached to "#representativeSubmit"
});
```

The reason for your doubling posting is that your function attached to the submit function is executed and afterwards the submit event is given to the form as well.

Comment: nothing happens...Also I don't see anything in Firebug console

Comment: What is your form called at the moment? If it does not have the `id="form"` the code won't work.

Comment: Sorry for not replying before - had to drop this and work out something else due to deadline.

Answer (score 0):

It sends duplicate data because you are binding to the `click` event of your submit button. After your bound function finishes, the form submits  -- triggering a `submit` event, but you did not bind to this so it sends another request.

You did not include the wrapping `form` in your code so I am going to assume it exists and somewhere above in your code

Change your line

```
$("#representativeSubmit").click(function() {
```

to

```
$("#representativeSubmit").closest('form').submit(function() {
```

This selects the wrapping form, and binds your routine to that form's submit event.

Also, can you confirm in your browser's developer tool if there are in fact 2 AJAX calls? If you are using Chrome, press F12 and to go the Network tab and filter by XHR. Do this before clicking anything.

[image]

Comment: I have changed as you suggested, but now "nothing" happens. I am not even seeing an error in Console of Firebug.

Comment: Do you have a `form` that wraps the form elements? Normally, `input type="submit"` will submit the form outside it. Also note that forms CAN NOT be nested.

Comment: Sorry for not replying before - had to drop this and work out something else due to deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Fix duplicate request ajax when click

```
$('#representativeSubmit').unbind().bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //.....
});
```